# Is it possible for me to 'see' an incoming ping?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ping

If I ping one of my servers from another server, is there any log or anything, a way to 'see' the ping from the other server on the target machine and identify it's source IP or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up [**Wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) on a PC and watch for the packets to come in there. NetMon is also an option on the server but I prefer to leave this type of analysis off the server.

If there is a gateway (firewall, router, etc) between your servers the ping should / could be logged at that device also depending on the log configuration of that device.

Comment: It'll probably be logged as "ICMP type 8, echo request"

Comment: NP. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes wireshark is the way to go...also use this process to actually strip out the traffic from the ip address that is pinging the server:

```
1) Fire up wireshark
2) Select the correct interface
3) Use the filter 'ip.src==192.168.2.1'
```

NOTE: you can use 'http and ip.src==192.168.2.1' to drill down into the protocol

Comment: Perhaps you meant `icmp and ip.src==192.168.2.1`? "Ping" is typically associated with ICMP echoes and replies.

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking about a Linux Server, the simplest thing you can do is:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 '(icmp)' -nn -vv
```

Considering that "eth0" is the interface from where the "ping packet" (icmp type 8) will come in.

Comment: Given the Windows-server-2003 tag, probably not talking about Linux server, no...